# A way to find the zookeeper ip's

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-cdh

On our (Cloudera CDH) cluster we have 3 ZK nodes running.
For parcelling purposes I'm looking for a way to get those node's IP's dynamically instead of hard-coding them.

Is there any environment variable or REST call that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you post the `zoo.cfg` of the systems running zookeeper servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have missed it, but the env var **ZK_QUORUM** does the trick!

from cloudera/cm_ext on github:

> If you add a dependency to ZooKeeper service, then any process in that
>   service
>
> (e.g. role daemon process, command process, client config deployment
>   process) will get the ZooKeeper quorum in ZK_QUORUM environment
>   variable. This can be used in the control script to add configuration
>   properties for the ZooKeeper quorum.